# jQuery: Limit the scope of a jQuery selector to avoid selecting other selectors that are not children

Tags: jquery

I have made a content shield (i.e. tabs) with jQuery. And it works perfectly.

I know want to put a second one on the page and then wrap them both within a larger content shield. However, when you click the links of the first one it starts effecting the second one.

This is an overview of my HTML

```
<div class="taptabs pages">
  <nav class="content-follower tapnav ui-ticklist cr-nav"> [UL NAVIGATION TO SWITCH BETWEEN CONTENT SHIELD 1 & 2] </nav>
  <div class="taptabs page">
    <nav class="content-follower tapnav ui-ticklist cr-nav"> [UL TABS FOR CONTENT SHEILD 1]
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="pages">
      <div class="page">
        CONTENT SHEILD 1 - Section a
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        CONTENT SHEILD 1 - Section b
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="taptabs page">
    <nav class="content-follower tapnav ui-ticklist cr-nav"> [UL TABS FOR CONTENT SHEILD 2]
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="pages">
      <div class="page">
        CONTENT SHEILD 2 - Section a
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        CONTENT SHEILD 2 - Section b
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".taptabs .tapnav li").live('click', function () {
        $(".page").hide().eq($(this).index()).show().addClass("animated").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    }).eq(0).addClass('selected');

});

})(jQuery);
```

[HERE IS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vNfRA/)

Obviously, the problem is that the taptabs/tapnav class is not specific to each section.
I thought I could use either [Closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to limit the selector, but I am not sure how to integrate it into the code, so the navigation only selects pages within its own section.

Comment: Use the child selector `E > F` and not the descendent selector `E F`

Comment: Your structure is inconsistent. The inner pages have a "pages" wrapper, but the outer pages don't.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNfRA/2/) for a quick idea. But actually, Šime Vidas is right twice: live is deprecated, your HTML structure should better be structured more consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. On the click event you obtain the correct parent and use it to filter the .page selector.

```
$(".taptabs .tapnav li").on('click', function()
        {
            taptab = $(this).parents(".taptabs").get(0);

            $(".page",taptab).hide().eq($(this).index()).show().addClass("animated").addClass("fadeInLeft");
        }).eq(0).addClass('selected');

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vNfRA/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific in your initial jQuery selector.  Using CSS notation, you can use the ">" (greater-than sign) to specify that you're only looking for direct children

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', ".taptabs > .tapnav > ul > li", function () {
            $(".page").hide().eq($(this).index()).show().addClass("animated").addClass("fadeInLeft");
        }).eq(0).addClass('selected');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT: I was previously using .live to be consistent with the original poster, but .live is deprecated in favor of .on(), so i've changed this answer accordingly

Comment: `".taptabs > .tapnav > ul > li"` - these types of long selectors are relatively slow. Use short selectors instead. Also, `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: The  `$(".page")` selector is still too general.